# Font issue with layer backed NSTextView

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, calayer, nstextview

I have a small problem with the `nstextview`, when I send `[textView setWantsLayer:YES]`, the font in the textView become blurred, anybody know why is it?

```
[[textView enclosingScrollView] setDrawsBackground:NO];
[textView setDrawsBackground:NO];
[textView setWantsLayer:YES]`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is likely with aliasing the text because the background color is transparent, thus causing it to alias against a transparent background, which is going to look pretty bad.

Generally, I've found that I can `[textView setWantsLayer: YES]` as long as I also `[textView setDrawsBackground: YES]` and set a background color that is opaque.

Good luck.